# Center align the div

Tags: html, css

Here is the link for my html
http://jsfiddle.net/9rprY/18/

In this I need the middle aqua colored div (#events) to come exactly center to the wrapper.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change CSS:

```
#events {
    margin: 0px auto; 
    padding: 48px 0px 10px 10px; 
    position:relative; 
    height:auto;
    width:320px;
    background-color:aqua;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9rprY/22/

Comment: Did u change anything else except #evnts css? coz wen i copy only this css to my style sheet, it is not working

Comment: I just changed #events style, nothing else. Ok, so i agan copied all ur css & html & changed just #event style, and its still working fine.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9rprY/47/

Answer (score 0):

Add the margin to 0 and auto in your css code, as below

```
#events {
margin: 0px auto; 
padding: 48px 0px 10px 10px; 
position:relative; 
height:auto; 
width:320px;
background-color:aqua
}
```

float:left; should be removed, I didn't noticed it previously hence edited the answer.

Comment: just remove the float:left; else everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#wrapper{
    width:600px; /* set width of wrapper div */
    display:block;
}
#event{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:320px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line:

```
float: left;
```

and *edit* `margin` and `height` as:

```
margin: 0 auto;
height: 25px;
```

[Here is you fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rprY/37/)

Comment: fixed height is baaaaaaad. take overflow or clear element instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this that you want. [here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rprY/44/).

Change #events css to

```
#events {
   margin: 10px 85px 14px 80px;
z-index: 100;
position: relative;
height: auto;
float: left;
width: 320px;
background-color: cyan;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

chnage events div css

```
#events {
margin: auto; 
padding: 48px 0px 10px 10px; 
position:relative;
min-height:40px;
height:auto;  
width:320px;
background-color:aqua
}
```

you can check in jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9rprY/54/

Comment: @Christoph  can you explain further that?

Comment: using height is error-prone, because you have to touch the parent, if you modify the children, e.g. change pading/fontsize or the client does not have the specified font, and suddenly has a larger one, which exceeds the parent-heigth. Also in the case of floats, min-height acts as normal height, and does not extend, if the children grow larger. Thats why it's safer (and cleaner) to use `clear` or overflow.